# android - how to manage background images without memory leaks?

Tags: android

Good morning,

in the process of writing my first android app, so please be patient.

I want to have background images for the activities I use. My first approach to add it simply to the layout of the activities,

```
....
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:tint="#dd000022" />
....
```

unfortunately this seems to lead to a memory leak when I call certain activities repeatedly. Finally I got hold of and found the reason why here [Avoid memory leaks on Android](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/)

My next thought would have been to do what Romain in above mentioned article calls a " very fast and also very wrong" solution - saving the bitmap in a static field or in the Application object.

I found various articles on this topic yet none of them seems to be aware of Romains point. Also I am not clear how to implement Romains solution.

Any hint how to handle images in android without running into memory leaks would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

martin

Comment: could you override the onFinish() and somehow dispose of the image there to ensure that the image is not leaked?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not just add a background to the layout you're using.

ex using linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    **REST OF LAYOUT HERE**
</LinearLayout>
```

or to use one image for all activities create your own style and apply then in you manifest

in your res/values add a styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and in manifest for each activity add

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, that was my first approach yet i couldnt find out how to color (tint) the background and scale it etc when used in this way. I would prefer to use a theme yet i use actionbar sherlock and havent figured out yet how to set the background image there without messing everything up.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry never worked with actionbar sherlock. You may want to modify the question for that purpose or create a new question. (Be sure to post what you tried that "messed everything up")

Comment: Also when i check now it still seems that memory usage adds up. Do I have to release the image in some way at onPause ...

Comment: No, not when using background images. Depending on the size of the image the eclipse memory tool may say it's a leak suspect even though it's not. Could be something else in your activity causing the leak? Does the heap size grow every time you go back to the activity? If it stays constant then you should be okay.

Comment: that background images dont lead to memory leaks is a very valuable information for me, as you already said I just have to figure out how to set it in my (abs) app - thanks again

Comment: No problem, sorry couldn't help for the actionbar. Good luck!

Comment: I use the same kind of layout and it doesn't solve the memory leak problem.